# docker run image, and it throws SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, docker

Hi I have a node app and when I run it locally everything runs perfectly.
Then I created a docker image of it and then tried to run the container for that image and it threw at me:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)

This is the function from which it complains.

```
router.route('/')
  .get(async function(request,response){
 try {
   const getAllFellas = await db_users.getAll();
   console.log("THE ALL OBJECT", getAllFellas);
   response.status(200).json(getAllFellas);
   // response.status.json(await db_users.create(request.body.name, 
   request.body.origin));
 }catch(err){
  console.log(err);
  response.status(500).json({'message': 'Server error'});
  }

 })
```

It is funny because when i check the syntax of it in tools for javascript spelling everything work correctly.

Any ideas what should I do to run my container?

Comment: Get a linter in your IDE. ESLint, JSHint, JSHint, etc

Comment: friend of mine try it and when he removed async  he said that it did work

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is there:

```
 request.body.origin)); <---- You've got 2  ' )) '
```

But in the code that you provided I cannot see any open ' (( '

Also at the end of your code you've got:

```
 })
```

But in the code provided I cannot see it where you open it.

Comment: router.route('/')
    .get(async function(request,response){
        try {
            const getAllFellas = await db_users.getAll();
            console.log("THE ALL OBJECT", getAllFellas);
            response.status(200).json(getAllFellas);

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({'message': 'Server error'});
        }

    })

Comment: request.body.origin)); <---- You've got 2  ' )) ' t

Comment: that is part of a comment

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code like below

```
// response.status.json(await db_users.create(request.body.name, 
request.body.origin));
```

Instead of

```
// response.status.json(await db_users.create(request.body.name,request.body.origin));
```

Sergiu already answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Idiots the Dockerfile has to start with
FROM node:8.0.2 or even latest version and mine starts with
FROM node:baron or node:argon 
thats why it thinks async or await is syntax error